# OWL Carousel 2 incorrect width, shows all items

Tags: javascript, css, owl-carousel

I have the following OWL Carousel 2 initialization code:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
            moment.locale('nl-NL');

            $("#owl-slider").owlCarousel({ 
              items: 1,
              responsive: false,
              nav : false,
              loop: false,
              dots: true,                  
              dotsEach: 1,
              autoplaySpeed : 300,
              dotsSpeed : 400,
              autoPlay: true,
              navRewind: true,
              animateOut: 'fadeOut'
            });

        });
```

This results in the following html of the carousel:

```
  <div class="item-list" id="newsblock">
    <div id="owl-slider" class="owl-carousel owl-theme owl-loaded">
        <div class="owl-stage-outer">
            <div class="owl-stage" style="transform: translate3d(-934px, 0px, 0px); transition: 0s; width: 1401px;">
                <div class="owl-item" style="width: 467px; margin-right: 0px;">
                    <div class="item">
                        <img width="100%" src="/SITES/FOCUS-DEV/NIEUWS/PUBLISHINGIMAGES/INKTPOT.PNG?RenditionID=5" data-themekey="#">
                        <div class="header">
                            <h2 class="title">
                                <a title="Nieuwsbericht" href="https://testprorail.sharepoint.com/sites/Focus-DEV/nieuws/Paginas/Nieuwsbericht.aspx" rel="bookmark">Nieuwsbericht</a>
                            </h2>
                            <div class="time">17 November</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div><div class="owl-item" style="width: 467px; margin-right: 0px;">
                    <div class="item">
                        <img width="100%" src="/SITES/FOCUS-DEV/NIEUWS/PUBLISHINGIMAGES/8628PEPERNOTEN-550X485.JPG?RenditionID=5" data-themekey="#">
                        <div class="header">
                            <h2 class="title">
                                <a title="Nog meer nieuws" href="https://testprorail.sharepoint.com/sites/Focus-DEV/nieuws/Paginas/Nog-meer-nieuws.aspx" rel="bookmark">Nog meer nieuws</a>
                            </h2>
                            <div class="time">17 November</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="owl-item active" style="width: 467px; margin-right: 0px;">
                    <div class="item">
                        <img width="100%" src="/SITES/FOCUS-DEV/NIEUWS/PUBLISHINGIMAGES/INKTPOT.PNG?RenditionID=5" data-themekey="#">
                        <div class="header">
                            <h2 class="title">
                                <a title="Test" href="https://testprorail.sharepoint.com/sites/Focus-DEV/nieuws/Paginas/test.aspx" rel="bookmark">Test</a>
                            </h2>
                            <div class="time">17 November</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><div class="owl-controls">
            <div class="owl-nav">
                <div class="owl-prev" style="display: none;">prev</div>
                <div class="owl-next" style="display: none;">next</div>
            </div>
            <div class="owl-dots" style="">
                <div class="owl-dot"><span></span></div>
                <div class="owl-dot"><span></span></div>
                <div class="owl-dot active"><span></span></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that the width of the owl-stage div is set to the width of all three items instead of 1. All items are shown instead of 1.

Please provide some guidance on what could be the solution!

Kind Regards.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem by adding this code to css:

```
.owl-item {
  float: left;
}
.owl-carousel {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Add singleItem:true to your javascript.

This will make it display only a single image at a time.

Comment: I've tried this and it doesnt work, singleItem is not even an option anymore in Owl Carousel 2

Answer (score -2):

The width of the owl stage div will always extend past the parent carousel container (div id="owl-slider" class="owl-carousel owl-theme") if there is more than one item in the carousel. This is easily fixed by setting overflow to hidden in your CSS.

```
.owl-carousel {
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: There is an "items" option that lets you identify how many slides you want displayed at a time. overflow: hidden should be set by default in Owls CSS.

Comment: He has items set to 1, and could possibly not be using the owl CSS.

Comment: I am using the owl css and items 1. I dont think overflow hidden is going to work because the carousel is now overflowing but the dots are also outside of the visible area, in the middle of the three images. Any other suggestions?

Comment: I'd try removing some some of the options one by one to see if that makes a difference. I'd start with the dots since that's the only difference I see between yours and mine. I assume that the carousel is functioning as expected? No console errors or anything? Can you post your CSS too?